# Getting generic overload by reflection for extension method in C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, extension-methods

I have following extensions class:

```
public static class KeyValueConfigurationCollectionExtensions
{
    public static string Get(this KeyValueConfigurationCollection collection, string key)
    {
        return collection[key].Value;
    }
    public static T Get<T>(this KeyValueConfigurationCollection collection, string key)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(collection[key].Value, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me how can I get overload for generic method (the 2nd one from the above example) by reflection? There is `AmbiguousMatchException` thrown at runtime for this line of code:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(KeyValueConfigurationCollectionExtensions).GetMethod("Get");
```

I know that there is an overload for `GetMethod` function where I can specify parameters but in that case those are the same for both methods. It would be great to solve that as I need it for my acceptance tests.

---

### Update

The simplest solution for me was:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(KeyValueConfigurationCollectionExtensions)
    .GetMethods().Single(method => method.Name == "Get" && method.IsGenericMethod);
```

Thanks guys for quick answers and wish you nice day :)

Comment: Don´t answer your question *within* your question. Either accept an existing one that solved your porblem, or post your own and accept this if none of the existing matches your needs.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks for the notice, will do in case of asking new question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the method that has generic arguments by calling [GetGenericArguments()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx), as in this example Linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var method = typeof(KeyValueConfigurationCollectionExtensions)
        .GetMethods()
        .Where(m => m.Name == "Get")
        .Where(m => m.GetGenericArguments().Any())
        .Single()
        .Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public static class KeyValueConfigurationCollectionExtensions
{
    public static string Get(this KeyValueConfigurationCollection collection, string key)
    {
        return collection[key].Value;
    }
    public static T Get<T>(this KeyValueConfigurationCollection collection, string key)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(collection[key].Value, typeof(T));
    }
}

public class KeyValueConfigurationCollection
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> this [string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("KEY: " + key, "VALUE: Hi!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acceptance for using LINQPad :)

Answer (score 2):

There´s also [`IsGenericMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isgenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) defined on `MethodInfo`:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(KeyValueConfigurationCollectionExtensions).GetMethods()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => g.Name == "Get" && x.IsGenericMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an overloaded method, then you have to use the GetMethods-method with linq:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(KeyValueConfigurationCollectionExtensions).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m=>m.Name=="Get"&&m.ContainsGenericParameters==true).MakeGenericMethod(new Type[]{yourtype});
```